# Mutate character column after interpolation

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following nested list:

```
# Nested list
df <- list(
  list(
    x = seq(0,100, length.out = 1500),
    y = seq(0,500, length.out = 1500),
    z = sort(rep(letters[1:2], length.out = 1500))),
  list(
    x = seq(0,100, length.out = 1480),
    y = seq(0,500, length.out = 1480),
    z = sort(rep(letters[1:2], length.out = 1480)))
)
```

where I interpolate the `y` values on the second list to be the same length as the `y` values on the first list. Then, the results would be like the following:

```
# Nested list
df <- list(
  list(
    x = seq(0,100, length.out = 1500),
    y = seq(0,500, length.out = 1500)),
  list(
    x = seq(0,100, length.out = 1500),
    y = seq(0,500, length.out = 1500))
)
```

The problem is that after interpolation, I loose the character values `z`. What I want to do now is to `mutate` or to `cbind` this character back. I can easily to do it for the first list, as it did not change its length. However, for the second list I need to `mutate` my characters `a` and `b` based on the values of `x` that they had before.

For example, if `a` had a `max` `x` value of 48.5, I need to `mutate` `a` to be up to 48.5 in the new list.

Any suggestions?

P.S.: I can't get the `z` from the first list and simply put in the second list, as my real list is much larger than this and they all differ.

## EDIT

My interpolation is done with the following function:

```
mylist <- df[[2]]
interp <- approxfun(mylist$x,mylist$y)(seq(0,100,length.out = 1500))
```

Comment: Question can be more clear if you provide your interpolation script

Comment: Please, provide some code so we can help you out

Comment: Please, check edits